# C# Hexadecimal to char

Tags: c#

I have a hexidecimal string with a length of 4, such as "003a".

What is the best way to convert this into a char? First convert to bytes and then to char?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
(char)Int16.Parse("003a", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

or

```
System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("003a", 16));
```

or

```
string str = "";
for(int i = 0; i<myHex.Length; i += 4)
    str += (char)Int16.Parse(myHex.Substring(i, 4), 
                             NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's the working code: 

char hexchar = (char)Int16.Parse("003a", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

Comment: System.Convert.ToUInt32("003a")-->System.Convert.ToUInt32("003a",16)

Comment: In System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("003a")); you need to provide the second parameter to ToUInt32 like System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("003a", 16));

Answer (score 7):

In 2020 I'd do it like this

```
char c = (char)0x3A;
```

If I needed it to be a string for use in removing a non-printable character, it would be like this

```
s = s.Replace($"{(char)0x3A}", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
label1.Text = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("0x00AC", 16)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First parse it using [`Int32.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx), then use [`Convert.ToChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx.aspx) .