# Replace hexadecimal value in string

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, replace, hex

I'm getting error `'', hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character. Line 440033, position 80.` Also see image:

[image]

It happens when I try to load the XML file into an XMLDocument.

I tried removing this hexadecimal value in a variety of ways, but none of them work:

```
        Regex.Replace(responseString, "0x03", String.Empty)
        Regex.Replace(responseString, "\0x03", String.Empty)

        responseString = Regex.Replace(responseString, "0x03", String.Empty)
        responseString = Regex.Replace(responseString, "\0x03", String.Empty)

        responseString = responseString.Replace("\0x03", String.Empty)
        responseString = responseString.Replace("0x03", String.Empty)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to replace a literal string "0x03", but the error message is complaining about a *byte* with a value 3. 0x03 is just the way the error handler chose to display the value (which is a non-printable control character).

Comment: Try `responseString = responseString.Replace(Chr(3), ""c)`

Comment: Thanks! With your suggestion however, I get these errors `Character constant must contain exactly one character.` and `Expression expected`...I'm also not sure what the trailing `c` is for in your code? Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now solved it as suggested in this post: [C# Hexadecimal to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874127/c-sharp-hexadecimal-to-char)

For me that was:

`responseString = responseString.Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("0x03", 16)), "")`